# scrapy can't start cause socket.error: [Errno 10060]

Tags: python, sockets, scrapy

I can't start all my scrapy project cause the error socket.error: [Errno 10060].
the detail error when start scrapy as follow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1585, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1015, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "D:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 7, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\reactor.py", line 39, in <module>
    default.install()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 196, in install
    reactor = SelectReactor()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 72, in __init__
    posixbase.PosixReactorBase.__init__(self)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 512, in __init__
    self.installWaker()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 284, in installWaker
    self.waker = self._wakerFactory(self)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 79, in __init__
    client.connect(server.getsockname())
  File "D:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10060]
```

my computer os is Windows 10

Comment: That means timeout. Make sure that the server that you're trying to connect to is up and not too busy.

Comment: I tried the website on my browser, it can connect. I think it's something wrong with my os setting,because there're no logs for init spiders or enginer